# Is a local inertial frame of reference a Lorentz frame?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, reference-frames

I started reading "[Gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation_%28book%29)" (the big black book with the apple) and in the first chapter it is said that a local inertial frame of reference rocks. A little later it is said that Lorentz frames rock. 
Are they identical or is one a special case of the other?

I know that the Lorentz frame comes from SR and describes a flat spacetime. However, I don't know anything about a local inertial frame of reference, except that it is the frame of a weightless thing/system/dude.

Comment: *"the big black book with the apple"* Yup, that sums MTW up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of these terms speak to their meanings.

1. Local inertial frames are **local**, meaning that they are only approximately inertial in a small region of spacetime. For example, the free-falling frame near our earth is roughly inertial close to the surface of earth, but becomes curved farther away.
2. Lorentz frames are defined as frames that preserve the Minkowski metric diag(-1,1,1,1). These frames are **globally** inertial, flat across the entirety of spacetime.

So yeah these two frames are treated as equivalent locally, but different globally.

Comment: Einstein says physics is always and everywhere LOCALLY lorentzian. So what do you mean when you say Lorentz frames are globally inertial? I thought you can always apply the Lorentz frame locally at some point to do physcis but not globally.

Comment: Lorentz frames are globally flat and thus globally inertial. It is like a tangent space to a more complicated spacetime. Imagine spacetime as a simple curved surface, then at each point on this surface, there is a tangent space that is globally flat. So as long as you don't get too far from this point, the flat approximation is good enough for all practical purposes. That is why you can treat globally curved spacetime as locally Lorentzian

Comment: Globally sounds like "go as far as you like" but at the same time you say that only in some neighbourhood this flat Lorentz-frame is good. This confuses me.

Comment: Global does mean "go as far as you like". That is why Lorentz frame models curved spacetime successfully near a point, but fails when you go too far.